# Matching a Swift protocol from an Objective-C Protocol instance

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging

I'm looking for a way to match dynamically an Objective-C `Protocol` instance with a corresponding Swift protocol.

I have a protocol defined in swift that is compatible with Objective-C:

```
@objc(YHMyProtocol) protocol MyProtocol { }
```

I try to perform the match, in a function:

```
public func existMatch(_ meta: Protocol) -> Bool {
    // Not working
    if meta is MyProtocol {
        return true
    }

    // Not working also
    if meta is MyProtocol.Protocol {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

This function is intended to be called from an Objective-C file:

```
if([Matcher existMatch:@protocol(YHMyProtocol)]) {
    /* Do Something */
}
```

The `existMatch` function always returns false.

I can not figure out how to solve this. Did I miss something in the implementation?

Comment: Possibly related: [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

Comment: Do you want to check if `meta` is strictly equivalent to `MyProtocol`, or is equivalent or derives from `MyProtocol`?

Comment: I would like to test if meta is compatible/conforms to `MyProtocol`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/protocol) is an opaque object type. It's defined in the generated header as:

```
// All methods of class Protocol are unavailable. 
// Use the functions in objc/runtime.h instead.

OBJC_AVAILABLE(10.0, 2.0, 9.0, 1.0, 2.0)
@interface Protocol : NSObject
@end
```

It doesn't conform to `MyProtocol`, so `is MyProtocol` cannot work. And, although Swift can implicitly bridge `@objc` protocol metatypes to `Protocol`, it appears that it cannot do the reverse; which is why `is MyProtocol.Protocol` doesn't work (but even if it did, it wouldn't work for *derived* protocols; as `P.Protocol` types can currently only hold the value `P.self`).

If you want to check that `meta` is a protocol type that is equivalent to, or derives from, `MyProtocol`, you can use the Obj-C runtime function [`protocol_conformsToProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418783-protocol_conformstoprotocol):

```
@objc(YHMyProtocol) protocol MyProtocol { }
@objc protocol DerviedMyProtocol : MyProtocol {}

@objc class Matcher : NSObject {
    @objc public class func existMatch(_ meta: Protocol) -> Bool {
        return protocol_conformsToProtocol(meta, MyProtocol.self)
    }
}

// the following Swift protocol types get implicitly bridged to Protocol instances
// when calling from Obj-C, @protocol gives you an equivalent Protocol instance.
print(Matcher.existMatch(MyProtocol.self)) // true
print(Matcher.existMatch(DerviedMyProtocol.self)) // true
```

If you *just* want to check that `meta` is equivalent to `MyProtocol`, you can use [`protocol_isEqual`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418705-protocol_isequal):

```
@objc class Matcher : NSObject {
    @objc public class func existMatch(_ meta: Protocol) -> Bool {
        return protocol_isEqual(meta, MyProtocol.self)
    }
}

print(Matcher.existMatch(MyProtocol.self)) // true
print(Matcher.existMatch(DerviedMyProtocol.self)) // false
```

Comment: That's it ! I did not suspect the existence of those functions. Thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: Happy to help @yageek :)